# maximize frame on startup in wxHaskell

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets, wxhaskell

How can I make window maximized on start with wxHaskell ? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I've never used wxHaskell before and have very little experience with wxWidgets, but if you take this line in the `HelloWorld.hs` example (available in the wxHaskell [source distribution](http://wxhaskell.sourceforge.net/download.html)):

```
f  <- frameCreate objectNull idAny "Hello world" rectZero frameDefaultStyle
```

and change it to this:

```
f  <- frameCreate objectNull idAny "Hello world" rectZero (frameDefaultStyle .|. wxMAXIMIZE)
```

the frame is maximized. Note that you also need to add `import Data.Bits ((.|.))` for the bitwise or operator.

I've only tested this on Arch Linux with `wx-0.12.1.6`, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't work elsewhere.

Comment: This is the correct approach - it should work on all platforms. It's a bug if it does not.